# Select result in single cell

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I select all id's for records in single cell?

For example:

```
--example select of all values
select id, name, address, phone from table
```

And get all id's where phone like '%555%' and show them in single field like:
'111 123 234 321 231 234'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[If you are using Oracle 11gR2:](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php)

```
select LISTAGG(id, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) from table
```

If you are not running Oracle 11gR2, check if wm_concat function is available and do:

```
select wm_concat(id) from table
```

Keep in mind that you might want to combine these functions with group by clauses. Check out link I gave you for more options.